# If $a\pmod 3 \equiv 1$ and $b\pmod 3 \equiv 2$, then $ab \pmod 3 \equiv 2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm stuck on this this problem:

> Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers with $a\pmod 3 \equiv 1$ and $b\pmod 3 \equiv 2$.  Prove that $ab \pmod 3 \equiv 2$.

I think the first step for the direct proof is:

$$ a \pmod 3 \equiv 1 \to \exists x \in \mathbb{Z},\,[3x + 1 = a] $$

I am unsure where to proceed from there.

Comment: That is the correct first step.  Now do the same for $b$ using some $y\in\mathbb{Z}$ and try multiplying the two alternative representations for $a$ and $b$ and see what happens

Comment: Proper LaTeX way to get $a \pmod 3$ is `a \pmod 3`.

Comment: So the second step would be:
$$ b \pmod 3 \equiv 2 \to \exists x \in \mathbb{Z},\,[3b + 2 = a] $$
but I am still unsure about the manipulation to show that
$$ ab \pmod 3 \equiv 2 $$

Comment: To be pedantic, I point out that the *original* (and for mathematicians, right) way to write these relations is “$a\equiv b\pmod3$”. What’s going on is that $\equiv$ is a verb, and “modulo $3$” is an adverb modifying that verb. In Gauss’s Latin, “modulo $3$” means “with respect to the modulus $3$”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: By definition, $$c\mod 3=d$$ means that there is some integer $y$ such that $$c=3y+d.$$

Hence, by assumption, there exist integers $y,z$ such that $$a=3y+1$$ and $$b=3z+2.$$ What is $ab,$ then? Can you find some integer $w$ such that $ab=3w+2$?